# Banner image is not rendering properly in the Outlook notification

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have a banner image added to the notification and dimension i set and Width: 100% & height: auto which is working fine in Mobile, Gmail but not working properly in Outlook.

My sample code:

```html
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><img style="align: baseline;" title="" src="sampleimage.jpgx" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" align="baseline" border="" hspace="" vspace="" /></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="height: 40px;" colspan="5">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Your request is submitted&nbsp;(${number}).</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="5"><strong>Title</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color: black;" colspan="5">${short_description}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="3"><strong>Submitted by</strong></td>
<td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="1"><strong>Approver</strong></td>
<td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="1"><strong>Department</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color: black;" colspan="3">${submitter}</td>
<td style="color: black;" colspan="1">${u_project_manager}</td>
<td style="color: black;" colspan="1"><span style="font-family: museo-sans, sans-serif;">${department}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #e6e7e8; color: #396b53;" colspan="5"><strong>Business case&nbsp;</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color: black;" colspan="5">
<p>${business_case}</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<p><span style="font-size: 10pt;"><span style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;">Thank you,</span><br /></span></p>
<p>&nbsp;Service Desk</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

[image: Outlook Output]

[image: Gmail Output]

I want to resize the banner image size, if i set the width & height with some values the image quality is getting disturbed and getting different outputs in different systems majorly on IOS & Outlook

Comment: You need to set some height in any unit

Comment: Sorry @Awais i didnt get that

Comment: I mean you need to set `height` on which banner looks good like `30px` or `4em`

Comment: Sorry it is decreasing the image height when i kepth height: 30px, and as said quality is getting cut off

Comment: I just use these values as an example you can change it to to actual size of the image and also try to use `object-fit: cover` on `img`

Comment: My actual size of the image is 2500X625. It is setting bigggg

Comment: Ok then use some width like `150px` or `180px` which the banner default size are and use `object-fit:cover`

Comment: Not working sorry

Comment: can you make a snippet of your minimal code

Comment: I didnt get your point but there is a sample of using media quires https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/BaBQgGZ

Comment: @Awais i already tried but it is not rendering only for outlook. Can you please ping me at gmail so i can connect with you and show where i am getting an issue.

Comment: Can you post both images what you need and what you have i suggest you to have a look at this link https://stripo.email/templates/brand/outlook/ and their html structure and also did you tried that https://litmus.com/